# Largest positive eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, information-theory, diagonalization

I am dealing with the Capacity of constrained noiseless communication channels. It has been said that the channel capacity of such a channel is $\log{\lambda}$, which $\lambda$ is the largest positive eigenvalue of the *state transition matrix*, however I wonder what if the largest positive value of such a matrix is complex. Can anyone tell the conditions which the matrix must satisfy till the ***largest positive eigenvalue of that matrix be real, not complex***?

Comment: @daw But the state transition matrices are not symmetric. Can non-symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State-transition matrices necessarily have non-negative entries.  By the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), the eigenvalue with the greatest absolute value must be positive (and of course real) for any matrix with non-negative entries.